# PHPMailer GMail Email sent but ..not received

Tags: gmail, phpmailer

I have installed PHPMailer 6 and use it in an MVC application, as per the below,my email is apparently sent, but never received  :

```
// Controller:

$this->sendmailer = new PHPMailer(true);
        //$this->sendmailer->isSMTP();
        $this->sendmailer->SMTPDebug = 2;
        $this->sendmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
        $this->sendmailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $this->sendmailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $this->sendmailer->Port = 587;
        $this->sendmailer->Username = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com';
        $this->sendmailer->Password = 'xxxxxxx';
        $this->sendmailer->setFrom('xxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'Test PHPMailer / GMail');

// In the inherited Controller...:


$mail=$this->sendmailer;

$subject="Mail Subject....";
$content="HTML content";

    $mail->addAddress('jmbrosselin@jmbdev.com', 'JM Brosselin');
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->isHTML();
    $mail->msgHTML($content);

    echo '<pre>';
        echo $message;
        echo '<br/><hr><br/>';
        print_r($mail);
echo '</pre>';
    die();
```

Note 1:  I have commented out the isSMTP() method which crashed the sendout, whatever the SMTP config i use (tls/587 or ssl /465...); Either than that, the email output seems correct ; 
Note 2: I have tested this config in a more simple non-MVC style and it works perfectly, eg, it is sent..AND received !

Oups..forgot to add the send method in the code transcript..obviously I had it inthe original script:

```
if (!$mail->send()) {
            $message='<br/>Mailer Error: '. $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            $message='<br/>Message sent!';
        }
```

HI !
and thanks to @Dhruvadeep.
I'm using a French Google / Admin console so the menus are somewhat different, but I did enforce the 'less secure Apps Control' ; what I'm NOT doing is using the 
"`require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';`" instruction; instead, I use Composer and the following:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```

in my 'controller'...
I seem to have read that "`require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';`" was outdated , I'm using v6.1.4 of PHPMailer…
is this correct ?

In fact, as configured, the Gmail requests works 'randomly' (…!) and takes a hell of a time to either get the mai out to the recipient email box, or ..not ! I have read that this could be due to GMail considering that I am sending spam ..But would this not be filtered / from the recipient mailbox, rather than from the issuing party (eg GMAIL …) ?

Below my current setup:

```
$this->sendmailer = new PHPMailer(true);
//$this->sendmailer->isSMTP();
$this->sendmailer->SMTPDebug = 2;

$this->sendmailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
//$this->sendmailer->Host =gethostbyname("smtp.gmail.com");
$this->sendmailer->Port = 587;
$this->sendmailer->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
$this->sendmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$this->sendmailer->Username = 'my_gmail_email_email@gmail.com';
$this->sendmailer->Password = 'my_gmail_email_pwd';
$this->sendmailer->setFrom('my_gmail_email_email', 'Test');
```

Comment: Uh, this code doesn't call `send()` so nothing will go anywhere.

Comment: Added the send instruction in the code transcription !!

Comment: Enable SMTP and show the SMTP transcript

Comment: Here is what I get when enabling SMTP, and debug = 2:<br/>

With the 587/tls Config:

2020-04-08 21:01:01 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)<br>
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting<br>

Comment: With the ssl/ 465 Config:<br/>

...
2020-04-08 21:04:33 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: EHLO test.soulabail.fr<br>
...
2020-04-08 21:04:33 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: [credentials hidden]<br>
&lt;https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&amp;scc=1&amp;Please log in via your web browser and then try again.534-5.7.14  Learn more at534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 f187sm964588wme.9 - gsmtp<br>
2020-04-08 21:04:34 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.<br>
2020-04-08 21:04:34 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: QUIT<br>

Comment: Right, so do what it says, and read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide which explains how to deal with this exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually use th3 latest PhPMailer guide as stated below.
Also activate Google Less Secure App by the following

**Enabling less secure apps to access Gmail

Open your Google Admin console (admin.google.com).
Click Security > Basic settings .

Under Less secure apps, select Go to settings for less secure apps .

In the subwindow, select the Enforce access to less secure apps for all users radio button. ...

Click the Save button.**

````
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Your Name');
$mail->addAddress('myfriend@example.net', 'My Friend');
$mail->Subject  = 'First PHPMailer Message';
$mail->Body     = 'Hi! This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.';
if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}```
````